# Is it impossible to update 9.10 since it is no longer supported?

Tags: apt, 9.10, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software on an old now unsupported Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version)

My organization has a server that has been running karmic for a long time. I'm working on a replacement server using 12.04 precise but before I make the switch I wanted to install the chef client on the box so I could tie it into a nagios package and monitor it.

Following the instructions on [this page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Installing+Chef+Client+on+Ubuntu+or+Debian) I get to the point where I try and do:

```
sudo apt-get install opscode-keyring
```

to which the system responds

```
opscode-keyring: Depends: apt (>= 0.7.25) but 0.7.23.1ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

I'm assuing that means run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to get the newer version of `apt` before trying to install that package.

Of course doing that throws lots of not found errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dhcp3/dhcp3 \-   
client_3.1.2-1ubuntu7.3_i386.deb  404  Not Found
```

These boxes are running on `amazon ec2`

I get that this version is no longer "supported" and I'm trying to stop using it - but does that mean in the ubuntu world that after the last day of support for a version it just ceases to be able to install any of the updates?

Also, is there any way to force-upgrade something like `karmic` with the latest patches that were available before it was at end of life cycle?